# Handle a big api get call

Tags: javascript, api, loops, get, timeout

I currently working on an API call (in pure javascript) to get data from an extern server. Im kind of new to API calls and im stuck right now. The problem is that the file that im calling for is really big and the call takes forever.

So i was wondering if there is a way for me to only get like 50 000 rows at a time or something like that. Just to make it work.

**Here is the API :**

```
loadLibrary("cus:json3.js"); 


var buffer = new MemoryBuffer();
buffer.fromString("username:password", "utf-8");

var http = new HttpClientRequest();
http.header["Authorization"] = "Basic " + buffer.toBase64();
this.baseURL = "https://url...";
http.url = this.baseURL;

http.method = "GET";
http.execute();

var res = String(http.response.body);
var lines = res.split("\r");

var c = 0;
for each (var line in lines) {

  if (c == 100) {

  try {
    var json = JSON.parse(line);
    logInfo( "Address: " + json.Address + " id: " + json.id);
    }
  catch(e) { logInfo(e); }

  }
   c++;
}
logInfo(c);
```

Comment: Do you control the service you're reading the data from?

Comment: I do not, but I know the guy who does. What did you have in mind?

Comment: Well if the service offered a way of requesting just a page of data (e.g., by specifying `startRow=x&pageSize=y` or similar) then you could request as many rows as you want at a time. I don't know why the end user would want more than 50,000 rows at once, or even more than 1,000 at once...